# MySQL declare a user defined variable inside select statement but do not show it as column

Tags: mysql, insert

I'm constructing a select statement that will later be the value of an insert statement.
Most of the columns will be calculated fields. I recently learned that you can reuse calculated fields during select:

```
select
  id,
  @sum1 := col1 + col2 as colSum1,
  @total1 := @sum1 + col3 as colTotal1,
  @gtotal := @sum1 + total1 as colGTotal
```

the result set will be 4 columns: `id`, `colSum1`, `colTotal1`, and `colGTotal`.
I need the resulting column to be just the last column `colGTotal`.

Again this select statement will be a value of an insert.

```
INSERT INTO tbltest VALUES (SELECT...)
```

I just need to insert the `colGTotal`

So I guess what I need is variable declaration and assignment inside the select statement (can't be outside) but EXCLUDE it as one of the resulting columns to be fed on the insert statement.

Answer (score 0):

If you can, rewrite your query to yield a single column:

```
select col1 + col2 + col1 + col2 + col3 as colGTotal
```

alternatively, you can can use this SELECT statement as a subquery, and SELECT just the column you want on it:

```
INSERT INTO tbltest VALUES (SELECT colGTotal FROM (SELECT id, @sum1 ...) AS foo)
```

Comment: hi jrouquie thanks for the response. Yeah my buds are suggesting the first option too. Tried it and my problem is that I had to repeat all calculations on each column. Option 2 might be more applicable to me. I haven't thought of that actually. Will try it and will get back to you. Big thanks.

Comment: 2nd option worked out well. Damn I forgot the basics. Again, big thanks. Will check out speed now.